# Developing Android application having Image and audio

Tags: android, html, web-applications, storage, hybrid

I am in process of designing an Android App :a poetry application, which would

a. display the poetry

b. audio controls - start, stop, restart, move for poetry

There are currently collection of 25 poems and it may update in future.

One way is to

**Approach 1**. Make a static app with all available content and update the app regulary with newer contents
Advantage: Easy to develop as everything is static
Disadvantage: App would be heavy as it would contain lot of content.

**Approach 2** Is it possible to put content seperately from the app,ex. app is installed and the content is placed on external storage memory. Using this mechanism, everytime there is a update, the content can be replaced with new contents (approach 2 = a very light weight player capable of showing content (may be in form of image) and audio capabilities + a separate location where content (images+mp3) are placed)

**Approach 3**. Make a hybrid app, as the user request for a content , the content is downloaded at run time and played using android audio capabilites.

**Approach 4**. Make pure HTML5 based web app.

Is there any other possibility ? Which option is more beneficial from user experience point of view.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: It depends on the infrastructure you have, or what you can build from your resources. If you have a large server, which you can configure to send data for a lot of clients (like youtube), streaming is a nice option for audio (approach 3). However if the server reliability is not that great, i would suggest the approach 2, where the user can decide whether he wants to download more content or it is sent out in updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with **Approach 2,5**, it is a mix of **Approach 2** and **Approach 3** where you save the downloaded file to a database so you do not download the same file multiple times and then play it.

Some clarification, as I understood **Approach 2** would only have more poems if there was a Google Play update and **Approach 3** was streaming. Using **Approach 2,5** you will get the storage from **Approach 2** and the playback from **Approach 3**.

Update: The term I was looking for was to synchronize data. **Approach 2,5** is really just a way to download for instance a JSON and parse it then download the files and put it in a database where the app later can access it. With this approach the user need not update the app and if you want to remove a poem that is also possible.

Comment: approach 2: with app update, the existing content database would be replaced with a newer one.